# PSobject output into console

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, output

i'm new to .net. Fall into a problem with outputing powershell command into console, invoked in c#.

Code:

```
    PowerShell powershellCommand = PowerShell.Create();
    powershellCommand.AddScript("get-process");
    Collection<PSObject> results = powershellCommand.Invoke();
    foreach (PSObject result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(results);
    }
    Console.Read();
```

Output:
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]

Comment: I guess `Console.WriteLine(result_s_);`should rather be `Console.WriteLine(result)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over your collection, but you are not writing the current item, but the collection as a whole. You have to write the item:

```
PowerShell powershellCommand = PowerShell.Create();
powershellCommand.AddScript("get-process");
Collection<PSObject> results = powershellCommand.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result); //<-- result NOT results
}
Console.Read();
```